# AngularJS view rendering issue

Tags: css, layout, angularjs

I am using ng-view to render dynamic data on my page. When the page loads, if I use static html I get this (top):

[image]

When Angular loads the page the data is there but it's like the element is still empty (bottom).

If I make even the slightest adjustment in Chrome dev tools, the items snap into place but I cannot get them to prefill without using CSS to make them static sizes, which doesn't work because text is different sizes. The elements in question have CSS of inline-block.

As you can see in this screenshot, I have tried two ways of populating the data, both with the same result:

```
<div class="cd-rating" ng-class="caseData.scoreClass">
    <span class="score" ng-bind="caseData.adjustedScore | number:0" ng-cloak>N/A</span>
    <span class="verdict">{{caseData.recommendation}}</span>
</div>
```

Here is the what the HTML looks like in the browser:

```
<div class="cd-rating medium" ng-class="caseData.scoreClass">
    <span class="score ng-binding" ng-bind="caseData.adjustedScore | number:0">349</span>
    <span class="verdict ng-binding">review</span>
</div>
```

If I hard-code that HTML identically, then it renders perfectly. It's only when Angularjs renders it that the elements are collapsed, appearing if there is not content.

I would also like to add that I am using RequireJS and manually bootstrapping the app instead of using the ng-app directive, in case that matters.

Any ideas on how to make the view fill the elements?

EDIT: Here is a video that demonstrates the behavior: http://youtu.be/zTwv-o6mWRM

Comment: It would be easier to solve this if you integrated your code into your question instead of referencing an image of it. There is code formatting on SO -- use the ` characters to bracket the code `like so`, or indent the code with 4 spaces.  Also, it makes your question self-contained to SO so if the hosted image goes dead, the Q & A is still relevant.

Comment: Yeah definitely post some code, a sample on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [plunker](http://plnkr.co/) would be even better.  From your screenshot it looks to me like there is actually an extra blank element pushing your displayed element over, not missing elements.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Unfortunately due to the complexity of the app and the backend API we are using that can't be access publicly, a jsfiddle isn't really an option. The problem is that the elements appear empty, as if there is no content. It's the exact element, it's just that the page seems to think it's empty. Sorry to waste your time.

Comment: Added more notes, code, and a video displaying the behavior. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to figure out what exactly you mean by the "..data is still there but the element is empty.." - the only issue that I find with the rendering by AngularJS is that the "Review" (button?) is overwritten with the number.

Looking at your code (which, as @Wingman4l7 suggests needs to be posted in the question rather than as a image), I see that you are using bindings to define a class dynamically. Instead, can you use the `ng-class` directive and see if it resolves the issue?

That is, replace:

```
<div class="cd-rating {{caseData.scoreClass}}">
```

with

```
<div class="cd-rating" ng-class="caseData.scoreClass">
```

instead and check if the issue gets resolved?

Comment: I tried that and updated the code above. Still didn't work. Also posted a video of the issue. Thanks for your time.